# C# Сервер не поддерживает защищенные соединения

Tags: c#, email

При правильных настройках получаю эту ошибку. В чем может быть проблема?

```
/// <summary>
/// Отправка письма на почтовый ящик C# mail send
/// </summary>
/// <param name="smtpServer">Имя SMTP-сервера</param>
/// <param name="from">Адрес отправителя</param>
/// <param name="password">пароль к почтовому ящику отправителя</param>
/// <param name="mailto">Адрес получателя</param>
/// <param name="caption">Тема письма</param>
/// <param name="message">Сообщение</param>
/// <param name="attachFile">Присоединенный файл</param>
/// <param name="port">Порт</param>
public static void SendMail(string smtpServer, string from, string password,
    string mailto, string caption, string message, string attachFile = null, int port = 25)
{
    try {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailto));
        mail.Subject = caption;
        mail.Body = message;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachFile))
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachFile));
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = smtpServer;
        client.Port = port;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from.Split('@')[0], password);
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Send(mail);
        mail.Dispose();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.Debug(e);
        throw new Exception("Mail.Send: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не доглядел

```
client.EnableSsl = false;
```